# My program prints out weird results: cycle@530daa cycle@530daa cycle@a62fc3 cycle@a62fc3

Tags: java

Is there a particular reason why this would happen or can it be for a lot of different reasons? I have no idea why my program is printing out the values that it is printing, because I was expecting it to print out integers. Instead I am getting this:

cycle@173a10f
cycle@a62fc3
cycle@a62fc3
cycle@a62fc3
cycle@530daa
cycle@a62fc3
cycle@a62fc3
cycle@530daa
cycle@a62fc3

This is part of the code: (I also have a cycle class, and a stack and queue class)

```
  import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;

public class PrintQ {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

     Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Whitney\\Desktop\\QueueIn.txt"));
     String job1;
     job1=inFile.next();

     char char1;
     int i=0;
     int FirstComma;
     int SecondComma;
     String charholder;

     QueueClass<cycle> list= new QueueClass(100);
     QueueClass<Integer> cyclelist= new QueueClass(100);
     cycle currentcycle= new cycle();
     cycle priorityCycle= new cycle();
     cycle Scycle= new cycle();


     while(inFile.hasNext()){

        switch(job1.charAt(0)) {

           case 'q': 
              {
                 FirstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                 SecondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                 currentcycle.jobNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(FirstComma+1,SecondComma));
                 currentcycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(SecondComma+1));
                 cyclelist.addQueue(currentcycle.cycleNumber);
                 list.addQueue(currentcycle);  
                 break;
              }

           case 'p': 
              {                    
                 FirstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                 SecondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                 priorityCycle.jobNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(FirstComma+1,SecondComma));
                 priorityCycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(SecondComma+1));
                 cyclelist.addQueue(priorityCycle.cycleNumber);
                 list.priorityinsert(priorityCycle);
                 break;
              }

           case 's': 
              {
                 FirstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                 SecondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(','); 
                 Scycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(SecondComma+1));
                 list.addQueue(Scycle);
                 cyclelist.addQueue(Scycle.cycleNumber);
                 break;
              }

           case 'h': 
              {
                 StackClass<Integer> stackjob= new StackClass();
                 StackClass<Integer> stackcycle= new StackClass();
                 job1=(String) inFile.next();

                 while(inFile.hasNext()){

                    switch(job1.charAt(0)) {

                       case 'q':
                          {
                             FirstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                             SecondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                             currentcycle.jobNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(FirstComma+1,SecondComma));
                             currentcycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(SecondComma+1));
                             stackjob.push(currentcycle.jobNumber);
                             stackcycle.push(currentcycle.cycleNumber);
                             break;
                          }
                       case 'p':
                          {
                             FirstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                             SecondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                             priorityCycle.jobNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(FirstComma+1,SecondComma));
                             priorityCycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(SecondComma+1));
                             stackjob.push(priorityCycle.jobNumber);
                             stackcycle.push(priorityCycle.cycleNumber);
                             break;
                          }

                       case 's':
                          {
                             FirstComma=job1.indexOf(',');
                             SecondComma=job1.lastIndexOf(',');
                             Scycle.cycleNumber=0;
                             Scycle.cycleNumber=Integer.parseInt(job1.substring(SecondComma+1));
                             stackjob.push(0);
                             stackcycle.push(Scycle.cycleNumber); 
                             break;
                          }

                       case 'h': 
                          {
                             continue;
                          }

                    }
                    job1=(String) inFile.next();

                 }   
                 System.out.println();
                 System.out.println();

                 while((stackjob.isEmptyStack()==false) && (stackcycle.isEmptyStack()==false)) 
                 {
                    int printjob;
                    int printcycle;
                    Object peek;

                    printjob=stackjob.peek();
                    printcycle=stackcycle.peek();
                    System.out.println("Job Number: "+printjob+" "+"Cycles Remaining: "+printcycle);
                    stackcycle.pop();
                    stackjob.pop(); 

                 } 

                 continue;
              }           
        }
        job1=inFile.next();   
     }   

     cycle whilecurrent= new cycle();

     while(list.isEmptyQueue()==false) 
     {
        whilecurrent=list.front();
        int whilecurrentcycle= cyclelist.front();
        list.print();
        //System.out.println();

        while(whilecurrentcycle != 0)
        {
           whilecurrentcycle--;
           //System.out.println("loop "+whilecurrentcycle);  
        }
        //System.out.println();
        //System.out.println(whilecurrent);

        cyclelist.deleteQueue();
        list.deleteQueue();   
     }  
     System.out.println();
     list.print();
     System.out.println(); 
  }
```

}

Comment: Oh, just fyi, Java convention is that all class names start with an UPPERCASE letter, so `cycle` should be `Cycle`. Java convention is also that all variables should start with a lowercase letter, so `FirstComma` should be `firstComma` and same with `SecondComma`

Comment: ok thanks :) I will change those!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere you're printing `cycle` objects, and since you haven't overridden `cycle.toString()`, it's using the [default `toString` implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

To override the `toString` method of a class, you would need to write some code like below:

```
class Xxx {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append("Your");
         sb.append("Logic Here");
         return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks:) can you explain to me or point me in the right direction on how to override toString()?

Answer (score -1):

That's because you haven't overridden the default `toString()` method of the class you are trying to print.

Comment: Thanks:) can you explain to me or point me in the right direction on how to override toString()?